# Jquery load in same script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm sorry if this is already asked. I couldn't find it.

I'm making an AJAX chat system. It's going great, the only problem I'm having is that I need the chat to automatically refresh itself every second. I know this can be done with the `load()` function...

But I would like to refresh the div and the PHP inside it, now load it from another script.
My piece of code(JS):

```
    <script>   
    setInterval(function() {
    $('#container').load();
    }, 1000); </script>
```

And the div I want to reload/refresh every second:

```
<div class="container" id="container">
                  <?php
                  $queryChat    = $mysqli->query("SELECT id,message,username,date FROM chat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 10");
                  while($infoChat = $queryChat->fetch_array())
                  {
                  ?>
                    <div class="text">
                        <div class="name"><?php echo $infoChat['username']; ?></div>
                        <div class="time"><?php echo $infoChat['date']; ?></div>
                        <div class="body"><?php echo $infoChat['message']; ?></div>
                    </div>
                  <?php
                  }
                  ?>
                  </div>
```

And if I do `$('#container').load('index.php');` it will give me this(the site will also be very slow): $('#container').load('index.php');

Thank you very much for helping in advance! My English is also very bad due that it's not my mother language :-)

Comment: Write a script that just returns what should go into `#container`, and call that with `.load()` instead of calling the main `.index.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you think it will be cleaner to just `include()` your "message pooling" script inside your  `<div class="container" id="container">`, so that your main chat page will now have:

```
<div class="container" id="container">
<?php
include("chatScript.php");
?>
</div>
```

Then chatScript.php will contain:

```
<?php
    $queryChat    = $mysqli->query("SELECT id,message,username,date FROM chat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 10");
    while($infoChat = $queryChat->fetch_array())
    {
    ?>
    <div class="text">
        <div class="name"><?php echo $infoChat['username']; ?></div>
        <div class="time"><?php echo $infoChat['date']; ?></div>
        <div class="body"><?php echo $infoChat['message']; ?></div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

Then you can simply do

```
<script>
    setInterval(function() {
    $('#container').load();
    }, 1000); 
</script>
```

after loading `<div class="container" id="container">`.

Hope this helps